# How to change Autoprefixer options in Angular CLI project?

Tags: javascript, angular, autoprefixer

I am trying to use grid css in my Angular2 CLI project, however I get the following message:

`autoprefixer: IE supports only grid-row with / and span. You should add grid: false option to Autoprefixer and use some JS grid polyfill for full spec support`

I looked at https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer which explains how to set this option in a gulp file, however I'm not sure where in the Angular project I can configure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to pass options to autoprefixer in angular-cli 1.0 ([issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/5850#issuecomment-299844128)).

There are two options to fix the problem.

You can selectively disable prefixing inside for a single rule:

```
.grid-row {    
  /* autoprefixer: off */
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  // ... other IE-incompatible configuration
}
```

You can also use `ng eject` ([docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/eject.md)) to output the `webpack` config of your angular application and modify it.